# (GVM) 10 on Alpine issue

Tags: alpine-linux

While installing GVM10 on Alpine (Linux alp 5.4.12-1-virt) I get the following error after the command:

```
apk add gvmd gnutls-utils openvas-scanner greenbone-security-assistant python3 redis

ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  openvas-scanner (missing):
    required by: world[openvas-scanner]
```

I'm actually sticking to this guide:

```
https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Setting_up_GVM10
```

What should I do in order to solve the problem?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The `openvas-scanner` package is no longer available in Alpine version 3.11:

- [openvas-scanner on Alpine 3.11](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=openvas-scanner&branch=v3.11)
- [openvas-scanner on Alpine 3.10](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=openvas-scanner&branch=v3.10) (`6.0.0-r3`)

The simplest solution is downgrading the Alpine base image to 3.10 (if you're running a Docker image and free to pick a different base). However, using an older Alpine base is not an ideal solution.

Alternatively, you can work around this limitation by installing `openvas-scanner` of the Alpine 3.10 repo:

```
apk add gvmd gnutls-utils greenbone-security-assistant python3 redis
apk add openvas-scanner --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/community
```

This seems to be working currently on Alpine 3.11.
It has the side of downgrading several gvm packages (below), but otherwise there are no installation issues.

```
(1/24) Downgrading gvm-libs (11.0.0-r1 -> 10.0.0-r1)
(2/24) Downgrading greenbone-security-assistant (9.0.0-r0 -> 8.0.0-r4)
(4/24) Downgrading gvmd (9.0.0-r1 -> 8.0.0-r3)
```

Comment: thanks a lot that's what I was thinking right now I'm installing Alpine 3.10..by the way are there any significant differences between 3.11 and 3.10..

Comment: well actually as you said it's not the right thing to do I mean installing the 3.10 version...I tried...but I got the same issue..so I'll do what you suggested ..thanks

Comment: @terence Using older Alpine is not ideal, because you want to enjoy the latest package updates and security fixes, but it's still a perfectly valid solution. If Alpine 3.10 works for you, then I suggest you go ahead with it. You can see the updates to Alpine 3.11 in the release notes: https://www.alpinelinux.org/posts/Alpine-3.11.0-released.html